# sql or excel mapping

Tags: sql, excel, validation, mapping

any body can help with the mapping in (excel,sql) i have been looking in youtube but i am not getting quite good one .
There is a opportunity to the person who knows it well to post a video on youtube :)

Comment: Mapping?  What mapping?

Comment: Me no understand a thing. Maybe it's me. Lemme get 4 or 5 beers and I'll read this again. Maybe I'm gonna get it then.

Comment: Talk about `Excel` and `DataBase` IMO there are only 1. Import data from an excel file to table in database and 2. Export records from table from database to an excel file. Is that you mean `mapping`? Or what do you want to talk about?

Comment: i just want to know what is a database mapping ? is there a necessity of having too many source for a target or vice versa . ? though my questions are weird as i don't have much of understanding please bear them .Thank you